# Add update dynamically table contents. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

am building my table using data coming from the database. On my html page, i'm able to see table and its content. But when i right click in order to view the source code, i don't see anything on the dom. can anyone assist.

```
//build list of booking
async function get_booking() {
    let res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/booking/today/%27);
    let data = await res.json();


    //build table
    const len = data.length;
    if (len > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML += 
            <tr class="d">
                <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                <td data-agent ="${data[i].coy}" >${data[i].name}</t>
                <td data-trip="${data[i].trip}">${data[i].trip}</td>
                <td data-busstop="${data[i].bus_stop}" >${data[i].bus_stop}</td>
                <td data-startdate="${data[i].start_date}">${data[i].start_date}</td>
                <td data-end="${data[i].end_date}">${data[i].end_date}</td>
                <td data-departure="${data[i].departure}">${data[i].departure}</td>
                <td><button class="update" data-booking="${data[i].id}" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
            </tr>;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal.Because the source is allways the original source of the page(which is page loaded tags) and it doesn't show changes made after page loaded. If you want to check the source after changes you must use a tool like chrome developer tools or firebug.

```
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

https://getfirebug.com/
```

Comment: Now when i  try to add an eventListener to all the buttons in that table, it doesn't work. I just receive an empty list.